# Updating multiple rows with Count of another table's specific rows with distinct foreign keys

Tags: sql, sql-update, sql-server-2012

I have a trigger on my table Views which records all views to a specific page. This trigger updates Companies table with total views, which should be derived by the inserted field. In practical situation it should never happen that one company gets multiple views (so just selecting all of them and adding one should be enough), but I like coding safely, so...

Companies:
Id, Views

CompanyViews:
Id, CompanyId

Needed trigger:

```
UPDATE Companies 
    SET Views = Views + (SELECT Count(1) FROM INSERTED  AS i WHERE i.CompanyId = Id) 
    WHERE Id IN (SELECT DISTINCT(CompanyId) FROM INSERTED)
```

However, this ... doesn't work. I'm not quite sure why, but basically the intended result is as follows:
Say, inserted table has

```
Id, CompanyId
1   2
2   2
3   3
4   5
5   2
6   3
```

In this case, Company 2 would get 3 views, company 3 would get 2 views and company 5 would get 1 view.

How should I go about this when my query has failed?

EDIT: By "doesn't work", I mean, the values remain unchanged. In fact it inserts NULL instead to the rows it does detect (ie the DISTINCT values). If I leave out the Views +, it'll simply make it 0.

Comment: Why do you need to store a value in the `Views` column via a trigger? You can always derive these counts at runtime using a query. If calculating the aggregate at runtime is expensive, use an indexed view instead of rolling your own maintenance and hiding this computation in a trigger.

Comment: Because even an indexed view is going to be taking a hit with billions of rows.

Comment: What hit do you think an indexed view will take that your trigger won't? Remember that an indexed view only materializes the number of rows identified by the unique index - in this case it will store, at most, the same number of rows as the companies table (subtracting companies with 0 views).

Comment: Another reason I don't want to use Indexed views is due to the fact that Company is fetched via Entity Framework and I can't really bind a view to a column there.

Comment: Also, it would be great if you could describe what "...doesn't work" means - do you get an error message? If so, what is it? Do you get unexpected results? If so, what are they?

Comment: Updated original post.

Answer (score 0):

No idea why you want to manually try to track this data using a trigger, and deal with concurrency issues, make sure you reduce the count for deletes in a separate trigger, etc. Instead I would just create an indexed view, and let SQL Server do the work for you:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.CompanyViewTotals
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
  SELECT CompanyId, Views = COUNT_BIG(*)
    FROM dbo.CompanyViews
    GROUP BY CompanyId;
GO
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX x ON dbo.CompanyViewTotals(CompanyId);
GO
```

Yes this has a toll on your inserts but so does your trigger. This has the added benefit of always being correct, allows you to drop your trigger, and allows you to drop the wasteful `Views` column on your `Companies` table. Even without the indexed view, this is obviously redundant data that you can already get without that column.

If you really can't get around all of these crappy limitations in Entity Framework, then you can do it the slow and unreliable way using triggers. You need to fix your update statement to use proper correlation between `inserted` and your base table, and to properly account for potential `NULL` values in the base table.

```
;WITH cte(CompanyId,NewViews) AS 
(
  SELECT CompanyId, COUNT(CompanyId) 
    FROM inserted 
    GROUP BY CompanyId
)
UPDATE c
  SET c.Views = COALESCE(c.Views, 0) + cte.NewViews
  FROM cte INNER JOIN dbo.Companies AS c
  ON cte.CompanyId = c.CompanyId;
```